# Promise.method() throws Unhandled rejection - why?

Tags: sequelize.js, bluebird

I don't understand why I get a

```
Unhandled rejection HttpError
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/makolb/devel/n4v_newsletter/app/controls/publishercontrol.js:31:23)
    at tryCatcher (/home/makolb/devel/n4v_newsletter/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23) [...]
```

which is the line with throw new HttpError(409); in my code:

```
var PublisherControl = {
    newPublisher: Promise.method(function (email, req) {
        models.Publisher.findOne({where: {email: email}}).then(function (publisher) {
            if (publisher !== undefined) {
                throw new HttpError(409);
            }
        }).then(function () {
            var password = Password.generate(12);
            models.Publisher.create({email: email, password: Password.hashPassword(password)}).then(function (publisher) {
                i_need_this_then_because_i_do_here_something();
                how_do_i_return_a_promise_if_return_publisher_is_not_enough();
                return publisher;
            });
        }).catch(function (err) {
            if (!(err instanceof HttpError)) {
                console.error('catched error: ' + err);
                throw new HttpError(500);
            } else {
                throw err;
            }
        });
    })
};
```

My mocha test looks like this:

```
describe.only('#newPublisher', function () {
    it('should create new publisher', function (done) {
        var Control = require('../../../app/controls/publishercontrol');
        Control.newPublisher('newpublisher@example.com').then(function (publisher) {
            should.exist(publisher);
            should.exist(publisher.email);
            publisher.email.should.eql('newpublisher@example.com');
            publisher.destroy();
            done();
        }).catch(HttpError, function (status) {
            should.not.exist(status);
            done();
        }).catch(done);
    });
});
```

So to clarify, I know why publisher is not undefined.
My question points to the bluebird part. I'd like to use the method as a promise and catch HttpErrors on this promise.
Shouldn't this work with Promise.method(...) ?
Can you explain this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not returning Promises anywhere, therefore the resolutions and rejections aren't being filtered through any `.then/catch` methods.  You also don't need to use `Promise.method` since you're already working with a function that returns Promises 100% of the time.

```
var PublisherControl = {
  newPublisher: function (email, req) {
    return models.Publisher.findOne({where: {email: email}})
     .then(function (publisher) {
       if (publisher !== undefined) {
         throw new HttpError(409);
       }
     })
     .then(function () {
       var password = Password.generate(12);
       return models.Publisher.create({
         email: email,
         password: Password.hashPassword(password)
       })
     })
     .catch(function (err) {
       if (!(err instanceof HttpError)) {
         console.error('catched error: ' + err);
         throw new HttpError(500);
       }

       throw err;
     });
   }
};
```

Comment: Ok. I've updated my code above... It makes sense what you say. But how do I return a promise if I use it already with then... create().then(...) - can I return the then as a promise?

Comment: You can mutate `publisher` however you want in that function, then return it.  It was removed in my example since it looked like an identity function that didn't do anything, however it's safe to re-add if you need to further process `publisher` after creation.